# Запустить wi-fi BCM43228 Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

Модуль работает на ОС установленных ранее. После переустановки ОС Ubuntu 16.04 x64 перестал определяться, в менеджере сети, адаптер wi-fi.
Пользуюсь [этой](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/broadcom) инструкцией.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [105b:e04b]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

предварительно скачал:

```
wget http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
```

решил запустить на чистой системе с live_cd ubuntu 16.04.3 x64

```
sudo dpkg -i '/media/ubuntu/428c4f8e-4a77-44ea-abd7-655ca90cb321/home/alex/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb' 
export FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DIR="/lib/firmware"
tar xjf broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
sudo dpkg -i '/media/ubuntu/428c4f8e-4a77-44ea-abd7-655ca90cb321/home/alex/b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb' 
sudo b43-fwcutter -w "$FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DIR" broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
sudo dpkg -i '/media/ubuntu/428c4f8e-4a77-44ea-abd7-655ca90cb321/home/alex/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb' 
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлен 194521 файл и каталог.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb …
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Распаковывается bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) на замену (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) …
Настраивается пакет bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) …
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.10.0-28-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.10.0-28-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic
update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media
```

build_make.log

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom for kernel 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Вс окт 29 03:53:06 UTC 2017
make: вход в каталог «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic»
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_alloc_linux_if’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
  dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
                                                                ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:8: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
        ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_dump_ver’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2047:3: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
   ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2047:13: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
             ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o»
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Ошибка 1
Makefile:1524: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build»
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build] Ошибка 2
make: выход из каталога «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic»
```

bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash

```
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom for kernel 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64)
 Вс окт 29 03:50:17 UTC 2017
 make: вход в каталог «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic»
 CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
 Using CFG80211 API
   LD      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/built-in.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
 /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_alloc_linux_if’:
 /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
   dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
                                                                 ^
 /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:8: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(priv_link_t), intf_name, ether_setup);
         ^
 /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_dump_ver’:
 /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2047:3: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
    __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
    ^
 /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2047:13: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
    __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
              ^
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 scripts/Makefile.build:294: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o»
 make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Ошибка 1
 Makefile:1524: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build»
 make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build] Ошибка 2
 make: выход из каталога «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic»
DKMSKernelVersion: 4.10.0-28-generic
Date: Sun Oct 29 03:50:23 2017
DuplicateSignature: dkms:bcmwl-kernel-source:6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2:/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:1354:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
Package: bcmwl-kernel-source 6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2
PackageVersion: 6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2
SourcePackage: bcmwl
Title: bcmwl-kernel-source 6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2: bcmwl kernel module failed to build
```

**UPD: 4**

```
sudo  modprobe  -r  b43
sudo  modprobe  b43
```

После выполнения вышестоящих команд, не смотря на ошибки удалось выйти в интернет через live_cd, однако через установленную систему вход не осуществляется.

```
sudo dpkg -i 'bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb'(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 177476 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb …
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Распаковывается bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) на замену (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) …
Настраивается пакет bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) …
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.10.0-37-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Обрабатываются триггеры для initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
sudo  modprobe  -r  b43
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/modules.dep.bin'

sudo depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

[голосуем за исправление бага](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1674568)

Comment: ifconfig его показывает?

Comment: Ну, так кто вам мешает найти и скопировать файлы фирмвари?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не показывает

Comment: последние 4 года у меня бродкомы заводятся на фрмварях из пакета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дополнение к решению в самом вопросе:

```
sudo nano wifi_run

> #!/bin/sh
> ### BEGIN INIT INFO
> # Provides:          wifi_run
> # Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
> # Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
> # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
> # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
> # Short-Description: modprobe restart for wi-fi
> # Description:       modprobe restart for wi-fi
> ### END INIT INFO 
> modprobe -r b43 
> modprobe b43

sudo chmod +x wifi_run
sudo cp wifi_run /etc/init.d/wifi_run 
update-rc.d wifi_run defaults
```